# Wrote cookie in VB.NET, how to extract in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cookies

I'v scoured the net for hours, but haven't found anything that can help. Probably doesn't help that I'm a total noob with javascript.

In my VB.NET code behind, I've created a multiple name/value pair cookie like this:

```
        Dim UserCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("UserInfo")
        UserCookie.Values.Add("UserNumber", Me.UserNumber.Text)
        UserCookie.Values.Add("Password", Me.Password.Text)
        UserCookie.Values.Add("UserName", Me.UserName.ToString)
        Response.Cookies.Add(UserCookie)
```

Now, what I need to do (somehow) is read that 'UserInfo' cookie in javascript and be able to extract those values at will. Most of what I'm finding out there doesn't *quite* do what I need to do.

I'm trying to do something *like* this:

```
var MyValue = ReadCookie("UserInfo", "UserName")
```

...And MyValue would equal whatever the user had typed into the textbox. I can't find anything like this and my javascript... well... I'm a noob.

Anybody know of any good resources?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Dear Lord, please don't send a password to a cookie!  Even if your connection is ssl, it's stored plain text on the local machine by the web browser

Comment: It's an in-house application (intranet). The "security" is application-level, a retarded feature of a 3rd party app I have to deal with. everybody here already has admin rights to the db, the 'password' is a serious joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [Quirks Mode's cookie page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using jQuery Cookie plugin [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).  jQuery is a library that makes using JavaScript easier.  jQuery is [here](http://jquery.com/)

To add a value to a cookie using jQuery, you would use:

```
$.cookie("myCookieItem", "true");
```

To read the value, use:

```
$.cookie("myCookieItem")
```

Comment: Sadly, jQuery is on the 'not-yet-approved' list of tools I currently drool over. Thank you, however, for the suggestion